# Calling AOPContext.currentProxy() from static method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I am using Spring's AOPContext.currentProxy() in a @service class implementation. However, i am using it in a static method and I do something like

```
public static void addCustomer() {
    //....

    ((CustomerService) AopContext.currentProxy()).addCustomer();

    //...
```

However, I am getting the error -- "cannot find proxy" set expose-proxy to true.

Is using static method the reason for this kind of error?

Note: "*addCustomer*" method is also static

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but you cannot do it this way at all.

Invocations of `static` methods are resolved at compile time, therefore they cannot be affected by proxy-based AOP. In other words:

- `AopContext.currentProxy()` inside a static method doesn't make sense (unless you want to get a proxy for enclosing call of some instance method), because invocation of static method is not proxied
- Calling a static method on an instance returned by `AopContext.currentProxy()` doesn't make sense, because it's resolved at compile time using a static type of expression, i.e. it compiles into `CustomerService.addCustomer()`.

Comment: that was a biggg bug i found i existing code and wanted to check if this doing it this way is indeed wrong. A static method is not associated with a bean and hence cannot get the proxy by calling AopContext.currentProxy(). M i write

Comment: @axtavt: I can't test it now, but I don't see why calling `AopContext.currentProxy()` inside a static method doesn't make sense. It gets its value from a thread local variable. Maybe it's confusing or not what the user expects, but I think it must work.

Answer (score 3):

Proxy configuration is injected at the time of the instance creation. Suppose Using this proxy created instance you are calling to the method AOP is applicable to that method. Suppose without proxy instance or using class name ( in the case of static ) you are calling to the method it is direct call proxy config is not injected to the instance, So AOP is not applicable to that method call.

Answer (score 0):

Does your configuration include something like `<aop:config expose-proxy="true" />`?